# Finding and summing values from one table, using positions of values from another table

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am keeping track of quiz results and trying to analyse our performance over multiple categories.

On one tab we keep track of each question's result (correct or incorrect) by date, and on another tab we keep track of each question's category, also by date.

I'm trying to create a third tab where we list each category, the total number of times a question in that category has appeared, and the total number of times we've correctly answered a question in that category.

All objectives but the very last are simple enough, I cannot find a formula combination that can take the position of a question based on the category and date, and find the corresponding question result (and then sum them)

An example spreadsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jMLCAhG9yu3LENDb_lo9NTyrLxr9leOeYjRNlGVp0Nc/edit?usp=sharing), but here's a brief description of each tab:

Results:

```
DATE    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1/1/23   1  0  1  1
1/2/23   1  0  1  0
1/3/23   0  1  1  1
```

Questions:

```
DATE    Q1       Q2       Q3         Q4
1/1/23  History  Animals  Sports     Music
1/2/23  Sports   Music    Geography  Movies
1/3/23  Movies   Music    Movies     History
```

Categories:

```
CATEGORY   COUNT 'TIMES CORRECT'
Animals    1     This is what I'm looking for
Geography  1
History    2
Movies     3
Music      3
Sports     2
```

I have tried various combinations of `INDEX`/`MATCH`, `FILTER`, `QUERY` but can't seem to find a combination that allows me to specify the position of one instance of a question (based on it's category) then find the corresponding result, then sum them in a single cell.

Comment: Did you try `SumIf()` or `SumIfS()` (the latter for multiple conditions)? And what about a pivot table?

Comment: Hi @Dominique, yes we've tried SUMIFS in combo with the above (I did not put an exhaustive list of formulas we've tried) but not pivot tables. I'll have a look at a pivot table now.
There are also some amazing suggestions below which I'm slowly working through to find an ideal result.

Comment: Sorry. I had misunderstood your question and I was only looking at the `Count` column. I've added an example, explaining the `Count` column and the `'Times correct'` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Countifs with the two ranges
`=COUNTIFS(Questions!$B$2:$K,A2,Results!$B$2:$K,1)`

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! I knew there was a simple solution I was overlooking. I've implemented this into our sheet. I have to manipulate rows if we miss entering some results, but for what we need this is perfect. I can't upvote answers as I've not got enough reputation but big ticks from me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula to `C2` cell. This will spill results automatically for `A2:A20`.

```
=BYROW(A2:A20,
LAMBDA(rw,SUM(MAP(FILTER(Questions!B1:K1,
BYCOL(Questions!B2:K8,LAMBDA(col,COUNTIFS(col,rw)))),
LAMBDA(x,FILTER(Results!B2:K8,Results!B1:K1=x))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(let(answers,B2:E4,
topics,B7:E9,
categories,A12:A17,
byrow(categories,lambda(r,sum(((topics=r)*answers))))))
```

[image]

or

```
=ArrayFormula(let(answers,B2:E4,
topics,B7:E9,
categories,A12:A17,
byrow(categories,lambda(r,COUNTIFS(answers,1,topics,r)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sum(index(if(ifna(xmatch(Questions!B2:K,Σ)),Results!B2:K,))))))
```

- It is assumed here that the dates in `Questions` and `Results` (***column_A***) will always be in same order. lets say for example todays date will definitely be in row 5 of both the questions/results tabs. if thats not goin' to be the sceanrio, let us know...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution, in my opinion, is the usage of `SumProduct()` with a condition (for using the "category" as a parameter), which looks as follows:

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$E$4,IF($B$7:$E$9=A12,1,0))
```

Screenshot:

[image: Explanatory screenshot]

- The idea of the `=IF()` is to get a zero when the category does not match and a one when it does.
- The blue arrows are a result of the "Trace Precedents" feature, which shows the input parameter of the selected formula.
- The "Count formula" and "Times correct formula" columns' content are the result of the `FormulaText()` function.

Comment: This response also worked perfectly. It's only slightly more complex than the `COUNTIFS` answer below but is simple and works perfectly. I've actually added this to our spreadsheet as a backup column. I can't upvote answers as I've not got enough reputation but big ticks from me!

Comment: I've also just realised I can't mark multiple answers as solutions, I would love to also add this as a second solution!

Comment: @Colinspocket: once you have reached 15 points of reputation, you might do an upvote. Just have some patience :-)